# Remove n elements from array dynamically and add to another array

Tags: ruby

```
nums= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
new_array=[]
```

How do I grab every two items divisible by 5 and add them to a new array.
This is the desired result:
the new_array should now contain these values

```
      [[5,10],[15,20],[25,30]]
```

Note: I want to do this without pushing them all into the array and then performing
array.each_slice(2). The process should happen dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
new_array = nums.select { |x| x % 5 == 0 }.each_slice(2).entries
```

No `push` involved.

Comment: Is there any way to do it w/o each slice?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `each_slice`?

Comment: Because I am going to try the same thing only this time using hash keys and values... Just wondering.

Comment: `Hash` supports `each_slice` too, just give it a try.

Comment: I wasn't aware of `Enumerable#entries`. I see it's the same thing as `Enumerable#to_a`. Olaf, one way to avoid using `Enumerable#each_slice` here is the following: `nums.select { |x| x % 10 == 0 }.map { |n| [n-5, n] }`.